# Ajax $.getJSON method to return html and json together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Is there a way to fetch html data and json data together from the server using ajax getjson or any other method.

For example,

**Fetch.php  contains following:**

```
$count=$conn->rowCount();
while($fetch=$query->fetch()) {
echo "This is data"; 
} 

$array=array("itemcount" => $count);
echo json_encode($array);
```

What I want from above fetch.php file is to return html data as well as $count value.

```
$.getJSON( 'fetch.php', {'id': uid}, function(data){
    $('#results').append(data);
   $('#offset').(data.itemcount); 
}
```

But this is not working. It seems getjson method is not designed to display html data. Then at the same time I could not display json with $.POST method either.  What is the solution to this problem then?

Thanks
Nikhil

Comment: You can use `.length` property i.e. `data.length`

Answer (score 0):

```
$count=$conn->rowCount();
while($fetch=$query->fetch()) {
$msg = "This is data"; 
} 

$array=array("msg" => $msg , "itemcount" => $count);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: this is good approach but for small html data. What if the html you are displaying inside loop is more than 100 lines.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.